# Join query In hibernate not return not maching record

Tags: hql

I have two tables `abc` and `device`

ABC :

```
   CREATE TABLE `abc (    
       `Id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,    
       `empid` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,    
       `empName` VARCHAR(500) DEFAULT NULL,    
      issueDate DATE DEFAULT NULL,    
       `deviceId` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,    
       PRIMARY KEY (`allochardwareId`),    
       FOREIGN KEY (`deviceId`) REFERENCES `device` (`deviceId`)    
     ) ENGINE=INNODB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

DEVICE

```
CREATE TABLE `device` (    
  `deviceId` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,    
  `deviceName` VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL,    
    quantity INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,     
       serialNo VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL  
  `deviceTypeId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,    
    PRIMARY KEY (`deviceId`),FOREIGN KEY (deviceTypeId`) REFERENCES `deviceType` (`deviceTypeId`);    
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Mapping file for `ABC`

```
<many-to-one name="device" class="com.model.device" cascade="all" >
   <meta attribute="default-value">new Device()</meta>
   <column name="deviceId" />
</many-to-one>
```

My requirement is that

- when a user searches for `deviceName` from the UI, it will fetch data first table and corresponding employee id assigned.
- If it not assigned need to return null value

How do I write this in HQL
I have written a sample query in SQL it works fine but I don't know how convert it into HQL.

It is the SQL query

```
SELECT *  
FROM abc 
LEFT JOIN device 
ON device.deviceId=abc.deviceId where device.serialNo="ee" and abc.empid="6"
```

I wrote the corresponding HQL as

```
select abc from ABC ABC LEFT JOIN abc.device where device.serialNo="ee"
```

here it returns only matching records in both tables. I need to retrieve records in such a way that even not matching also displayed with null values if record not found in another table.For example some records are available in device but not in ABC with serial no="ee" also need to displayed.